# Laravel 5.2 pagination: how to get less links in the bar (no custom paginators)?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-pagination

Is there an easy way to get less links in the Laravel 5.2 pagination bar, so that smartphone view is not broken and links appear all on one line? I know that there are ways to build custom paginators, but I was wondering if I could use the default one, only with less links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$result->simplePaginate(15);
```

Instead of the usual:

```
$result-paginate(15);
```

This will mean only the `previous` and `next` buttons will be displayed. If that doesn't suit your needs then you have two options:

1. Use a custom pagination class and edit to suit your needs
2. Use CSS to make the buttons work on mobile, or use jQuery to hide pagination buttons to make it all fit on mobile.

Comment: So there is not an easy way to do this, without a custom paginator... thanks anyway

Comment: Not really. The easiest way would be to use CSS / JS to hide / show links on mobile as needed.